# How to create an adjacency list from an edge list efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have a csv that looks like

```
id1,id2
a,b
c,d
a,e
c,f
c,g
```

I read it in  to a dataframe with df = pd.read_csv("file.csv").

I would like to convert it to an adjacency list. That is the output should be

```
a,b,e
c,d,f,g
```

I feel that df.groupby('id1') should help but variable length rows aren't suited to pandas so I am a little stuck. As my csv is large I am looking for an efficient solution however.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: what do you need at the end - a DF or a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need CSV strings:

```
In [107]: df.groupby('id1').id2.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
Out[107]:
  id1    id2
0   a    b,e
1   c  d,f,g
```

Comment: This is also a great answer. Now I won't know which one to accept.

Comment: @eleanora, just flip a coin! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed `groupby`, then `apply` `list`:

```
In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'], 'id2': ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']})

In [49]: df.id2.groupby(df.id1).apply(list)
Out[49]: 
id1
a       [b, e]
c    [d, f, g]
Name: id2, dtype: object
```

To write it to a CSV file, you can use

```
df1 = df.id2.groupby(df.id1).apply(list).apply(lambda l: ','.join(l)).reset_index()

df1.id1.str.cat(df1.id2, sep=',').to_csv('stuff.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Oh I had no idea thank you! If I want to output that as a csv in the form in the question  is that easy too?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('id1')['id2'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Another solution where output is list:

```
df.groupby('id1')['id2'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Comment: Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
adj = defaultdict(set)
for line in input:
    left, right = line.split(",")
    adj[left].add(right)
```

Output:

```
for k,v in adj.items():
    print("%s,%s" % (k, ",".join(v)))
```